# dask, execute non-serializable object on every worker

Tags: python, multithreading, serialization, dask

I am trying to execute the following graph:

[image: graph]

which is generated by the following code:

```
energies = [10, 20]
system = delayed(make_non_serializable_oject)(x=1)
trans = [delayed(some_function_that_uses_system)(system, energy) for energy in energies]
result = delayed(list)(trans)
result.visualize()
```

When I call `result.compute()` the calculation never finishes.

Calling `result.compute(get=dask.async.get_sync)`, and `result.compute(dask.threaded.get)` both do work. However `result.compute(dask.multiprocessing.get)` does not and generates the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-b5c8f2a1c6f6> in <module>()
----> 1 result.compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)

/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
     76             Extra keywords to forward to the scheduler ``get`` function.
     77         """
---> 78         return compute(self, **kwargs)[0]
     79 
     80     @classmethod

/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    169         dsk = merge(var.dask for var in variables)
    170     keys = [var._keys() for var in variables]
--> 171     results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    172 
    173     results_iter = iter(results)

/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py in get(dsk, keys, num_workers, func_loads, func_dumps, optimize_graph, **kwargs)
     81         # Run
     82         result = get_async(apply_async, len(pool._pool), dsk3, keys,
---> 83                            queue=queue, get_id=_process_get_id, **kwargs)
     84     finally:
     85         if cleanup:

/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/async.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, queue, get_id, raise_on_exception, rerun_exceptions_locally, callbacks, **kwargs)
    479                     _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    480                 else:
--> 481                     raise(remote_exception(res, tb))
    482             state['cache'][key] = res
    483             finish_task(dsk, key, state, results, keyorder.get)

RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 228, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "kwant/graph/core.pyx", line 664, in kwant.graph.core.CGraph_malloc.__cinit__ (kwant/graph/core.c:8330)
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 6 positional arguments (0 given)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback
---------
  File "/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 273, in execute_task
    queue.put(result)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 732, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
```

With `ipyparallel` I would execute the `make_non_serializable_oject` on each engine, which solves the problem for that case.

I would like to use `dask` for my parallel computations, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ensure that your data can be serialized

This code in your traceback shows that the objects from your `kwant` library are not serializing themselves well:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 228, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/home/bnijholt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "kwant/graph/core.pyx", line 664, in kwant.graph.core.CGraph_malloc.__cinit__ (kwant/graph/core.c:8330)
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 6 positional arguments (0 given)
```

Which is why the multiprocessing and distributed schedulers are failing.  Dask requires the ability to serialize data in order to move it around between different processes.

The simplest and cleanest way to solve this problem is to improve serialization of your data.  Ideally you can do this by improving `kwant`.  You could also manage this through dask's custom serialization, but that' possibly more work at the moment.

#### Keep data in one location

OK, so lets assume that you can't improve serialization and need to keep data where it is.  This will restrict you to embarrassingly parallel workflows (map).  There are two solutions:

1. Use the `fuse` optimization`
2. Track explicitly where tasks run

#### Fuse

You're going to create some unserializable data, then run stuff on it, then run a computation on it that turns it into something serializable before trying to move it back.  This is fine as long as the scheduler decides to never move the data around on its own.  You can enforce this by fusing all of those tasks into a single atomic task.  See the [optimization docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/optimize.html) for details

```
from dask.optimize import fuse
bad_data = [f(...) for ...]
good_data = [convert_to_serializable_data(bd) for bd in bad_data]
dask.compute(good_data, optimizations=[fuse])
```

#### Specify exactly where each computation should live yourself

See [Data Locality docs](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html)

Comment: `from dask.optimize import fuse` should now be `from dask.optimization import fuse`